# Select column one where column two is unique

Tags: mysql

I wasn't sure how to word my question, but here we go... With an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a table, which looks like this:

```
  -------------------
    X_ID  |  Y_ID
  -------------------
      2   |   8
      2   |   12
  --------------------
```

I want to return one row per X_ID, which has only one Y_ID for that X_ID.

I don't want to return a row if it has > 1 Y_ID, for a particular X_ID. And, I want to return only one row out of all X_IDs that match the above rule.

Using the table above as an example, I need a query that would return 0 rows for the data in that table.

I need the same query to return 1 row from the following table

```
  -------------------
    X_ID  |  Y_ID
  -------------------
      2   |   8
      2   |   12
      3   |   19
      3   |   19
  -------------------
```

I need a query that will return one row form this - either of the bottom 2.

I just need the X_ID.

I've tried just about as much as I can think of, using DISTINCT and GROUP BY.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, this would be more complicated in MSSQL since it would require you to group on X_ID and Y_ID; but this should work. Normally, the Y_ID in the results would be an effectively random selection of all the Y_ID values found in that group; but since we are specifically filtering out groups with more than one Y_ID, it ends up being the exact Y_ID you need.

```
SELECT X_ID, Y_ID 
FROM (
   SELECT X_ID, Y_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT Y_ID) AS yCount
   FROM theTable
   GROUP BY X_ID
   HAVING yCount = 1
) AS subQ
;
```

---

I'm not quite as well versed in the intricacies of MSSQL, but I *think* something this would work (for both MySQL and MSSQL).

```
SELECT t1.X_ID, t1.Y_ID
FROM theTable AS t1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT X_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT Y_ID) AS yCount
   FROM theTable
   GROUP BY X_ID
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Y_ID) = 1
) AS t2 ON X_ID
;
```

I say *think* because I am not 100% sure MSSQL supports `COUNT(DISTINCT value)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It should do what you want it to do.

```
SELECT X_ID, Y_ID FROM theTable
GROUP BY X_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT X_ID, Y_ID) = 1
```